# Force Camel JMS/AMQP component to use separate sessions for producer and consumer

Tags: apache-camel, spring-jms

Some AMQP enabled brokers like Microsoft Service Bus or ActiveMQ allow only one active producer or consumer per session. The Apache JMS Camel component seems not be able to handle this correctly, which result that JMS throws exceptions when processing InOut messages sent from e.g. Service Bus.

A small JMS test application with separate sessions for producer and consumer works nice. With using the same session, it run into the same problem.

Issue is rooted in the Spring JMS template, which is used as base for the Camel JMS implementation.

Does anybody know how to overcome that behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a 2nd JMS component and use that for the "other".
Or you can turn off any kind of connection pooling maybe.

If you use XML then you can define a 2nd jms component

```
<bean id="jms2" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent"/>
```